# How to reformat my input field in my custom input component?

Tags: vue.js, computed-properties

I made a component for my app's input form fields. In it:

```
<input
    type="number"
    :value="value"
    @input="$emit('input', $event.target.value)"
    @change="change"
/>
```

Works well, except now I want to automatically add a leading zero for numbers between 1 and 9:

```
change () {
  this.value = this.value.padStart(2, '0');
}
```

But, I'm getting this error:

> Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten
>   whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or
>   computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated:
>   "value"

Which I understand, but then how to achieve what I want in my component? I don't see how to apply this advice and use a computed property, what would I do with that computed property?

Answer (score 1):

Use `padStart` for your `$emit` instead `change`.

```
<input
    type="number"
    :value="value"
    @input="$emit('input', $event.target.value.padStart(2, '0
))"
    @change="change"
/>
```

Or better use computed property.

```
computed: {
  innerValue: {
    get() {
      return this.value;
    },
    set(val) {
      this.$emit('input', val.padStart(2, '0'));
    }
  }
}
```

Now in your native input you can use `v-model`

```
<input
    type="number"
    v-model="innerValue"
    @change="change"
/>
```

And you can use `v-model` in your custom component(wrapper for input)

```
<custon-component
  v-model="yourVariableFromData"
>
```